# appending strings in JS

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I need little help with JS function:

On the Image that I attached there is 3 textboxes and a button I want with JS 
to Take the first letter that is in the FirstName text box + the full text in the the LastName textbox and when the user click on the button it will appened the first letter + last name like in the Pic.thank to the helpres!!!

[image]

My code in JS:

```
function UserNameCreation_Click(sender, args) {
    var l_FirstName = $find("<%=txtFirstName.ClientID %>");
    var l_FirstNametxt = l_FirstName.get_value();

    var l_LastName = $find("<%=txtLastName.ClientID %>");
    var l_LastNametxt = l_LastName.get_value();

    var l_UserName = $find("<%=txtUserName.ClientID %>");
    var l_UserNametxt = l_UserName.get_value();

    l_UserNametxt = l_FirstNametxt.substring(0, 1) + l_LastNametxt;
}
```

asp code:

```
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" Width="200px"  MaxLength="50" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<telerik:RadButton ID="btnCreateUserName" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" AutoPostBack="false" Height="22px" Width="20px" OnClientClicked="UserNameCreation_Click" >
                                    <Icon PrimaryIconCssClass="rbEdit" PrimaryIconLeft="4" PrimaryIconTop="4" />
                                 </telerik:RadButton>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" Width="200px"  MaxLength="50" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" Width="200px" MaxLength="25" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: please provide full code or jsfiddle which will help better

Comment: So what is the question? The last line of your function seems to be doing the string concatenation you asked about, but then you don't do anything with the result.

Comment: I tried to create a function in JS that will behave like the pic: taking the first letter from First Name text box + what's was written in the Last Name text box and append that to User Name text box by client click on the button How can I do that? please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think most of the problem is you are not doing anything with the result of your string combination. Another possibility is you are using microsoft's functions, use vanilla javascript or a framework like jquery.

See an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/XDeP5/

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="txt1" />
<input type="text" id="txt2" />
<input type="button" id="btn" value="fill" />
<input type="text" id="txt3" />
```

Javascript

```
function fill() {
    var fName = document.getElementById('txt1').value;
    var lName = document.getElementById('txt2').value;
    var other = fName.substring(0,1) + lName;
    document.getElementById('txt3').value = other;
}
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = fill;
```

Comment: Can Someone please Can show me over my code what I'm doing worng??


   function UserNameCreation_Click(sender, args) {

        var l_FirstName = $find("<%=txtFirstName.ClientID %>");
        var l_FirstNametxt = l_FirstName.get_value();

        var l_LastName = $find("<%=txtLastName.ClientID %>");
        var l_LastNametxt = l_LastName.get_value();

        var l_UserName = $find("<%=txtUserName.ClientID %>");
        var l_UserNametxt = l_UserName.get_value();

        l_UserNametxt = l_FirstNametxt.substring(0, 1) + l_LastNametxt;
        l_UserName.set_value(l_UserNametxt);
    }

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a particular HTML with known IDs (you can substitute in your own ids) and that you want the first letter of the username capitalized and the second not capitalized (like in your example), here's code for that:

HTML:

```
First Name: <input id="firstName"><br>
Last Name: <input id="lastName"></br>
User Name: <input id="userName"><br>
<button id="makeUserName">Make User Name</button>
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("makeUserName").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var firstName, lastName, userName;
    firstName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
    lastName = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
    // make sure neither first or last name is empty
    if (firstName && lastName) {
        userName = firstName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + lastName.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + lastName.slice(1);
        document.getElementById("userName").value = userName;
    }
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/kpp7C/